# disable swipe gesture in xcode 4

Tags: xcode, macos, xcode4

Does anyone know how to disable the swipe gesture in Xcode 4 that causes you to jump to a new file?  I find that more times than not, this gesture causes me to switch to unintentionally move away from a file I am scanning (I suppose I was lazy before when scrolling up and down, so my fingers would also move horizontally).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You have to go outside Xcode and through System Preferences > Trackpad > More Gestures then un-tick 'Swipe between pages'.

Comment: Nice, thanks.  I can once again write really really long comments and not have to worry about switching to another file when scrolling to the end. :)

Comment: Is there a (easy) solution to disable it for Xcode (and probably some other apps) only? Thanks! :-)

Comment: Not that I know of (thats not to say there isn't though...)

Comment: shame i have to just disable it.  I like the feature on safari and HATE it on Xcode.

Comment: I agree this feature in XCode is annoying and a time waste.

Comment: odyth, just set it to 3 fingers - and then use 4 for fullscreen apps and mission control... not sure why they didn't do this in the first place. The issue for me is simply the conflict with the two finger scrolling in IB.

Comment: @RandyMarsh: see my answer below.

Answer (score 23):

The problem with Aaron's answer is that it disables the gesture completely in all the apps, including Safari. To disable it in Xcode only, type this in the Terminal:

```
defaults write com.apple.dt.Xcode AppleEnableSwipeNavigateWithScrolls -bool NO
```

([Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20024231/prevent-disable-xcode-scroll-navigation))

Note that you might have to restart Xcode for these changes to take effect.

Comment: This is the one true correct answer. It works for `Xcode 6` as well.

Comment: ...and it still works for Xcode 7. ...and it doesn't disable the gesture in other Apps. +1! Still, it should be mentioned that you might have to restart Xcode after running the command.

Comment: Thanks @JanNash, precision added :)