# Prevent / Disable Xcode scroll navigation

Tags: xcode

Whenever I am working with Xcode in storyboard mode and I scroll around with my trackpad. If I scroll too far to the left Xcode will take me to the last .m/.h file I was working on, and it is so frustrating. I don't want to be able to swipe two fingers left or right to navigate in Xcode. But i really like the feature for Safari and other applications.

Is there a way to disable navigational scrolling only for Xcode?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

To disable for trackpads:

```
defaults write com.apple.dt.Xcode AppleEnableSwipeNavigateWithScrolls -bool NO
```

To disable for the Magic Mouse:

```
defaults write com.apple.dt.Xcode AppleEnableMouseSwipeNavigateWithScrolls -bool NO
```

Should take effect the next time Xcode is launched.

Comment: Works for me to fix magic mouse which does not want to scroll in XCode (by setting YES instead of NO).

Comment: Brilliant, Xcode seems really sensitive to sideways movement on my mouse and hangs for a second frequently. Fixed!